# Automating filling an asp form which only has radio button and records only user clicks using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, automation

There is an ASP form which I need to fill recurringly so I thought of automating the process. But the thing is it only accepts user clicks and no other input method. That is, it records input only when user clicks on the radio button. I tried using:

`document.getElementsByName("elementName").value = my_value;`

but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are you using selenium?

Comment: No. I heard it is for testing purposes. Also, I'm kind of a noob here...correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: It's for automating browsers.  If that's what you are looking to do, then you can make it fit your purpose.  It supports lots of languages (e.g. python, ruby, js, java, C#).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll see if I can learn it, lol.